# Web и криптовалюта

Tags: php, javascript, python, веб-программирование, криптовалюта

Есть ли какие-нибудь реальные способы привязать на сайте покупку товаров с помощью известных криптовалют на сегодняшнее время?
Например, есть ли какие-нибудь доступные пакеты, API, которые позволят привязать это к сайту?
Если да, то есть ли примеры реализации?

Answer (score 1):

Для приёма биткоинтов уже существует масса сервисов со своими API, например:

https://ru.cryptonator.com

https://www.blockchain.com

https://www.coinbase.com

https://bitaps.com